# VB.Net, sending emails out uniquely

Tags: vb.net

im an intern at a packaging company and we have an interface that sends out summary emails out to several people on mondays. There are about 70 groups that the code sees. every group has a specific section that people enter a log in. if you are a recipient in that group on monday you will recieve a summary email of all the active logs entered for groups you are in. if user A is in group 1 and 2, he or she should recieve 2 emails with active logs pretaining to those 2 groups. Problem is he or she is signed up in all 70 groups and if there are only 2 active logs from group 1 and 2 she recieves 70 identical emails with summaries containing active logs for those 2 groups. here is the code.

```
 Private Sub SendEmails()
    Try

        Dim message As New PCA.Core.Messaging.Message(PCA.Core.Messaging.MessageTypes.JumperLog)
        'Dim distLists As List(Of PCA.Core.DistributionList) = (From r In Trident.Core.Globals.TridentApp.ApplicationCache.DistributionLists.DistributionLists Where r.ID.Contains("JL_")).ToList
        Dim distLists As List(Of PCA.Core.DistributionList) = (From r In PCA.Core.DistributionList.GetDistributionLists Where r.Id.Contains("JL_")).ToList

        For Each distlist As PCA.Core.DistributionList In distLists
            Dim recipients As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Trident.Core.User)
            recipients = Trident.Core.Core.Message.GetTridentDistributionList("TRIMAINT", distlist.Id)

            If recipients.Count > 0 Then
                message.Recipients.AddRange(recipients)
            End If

        Next

        If message.Recipients.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dbConn As New Trident.Core.DBConnection
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM ***.Maintenance.JumperLogs WHERE Removed <> 1 AND Plant = @Plant ORDER BY InstallDate "
        dbConn("@Plant") = Trident.Core.Globals.TridentApp.DefaultPlant.Plant

        Dim tmpJL As Trident.Objects.Maintenance.JumperLogs.JumperLog
        message.Subject = "Jumper Log - Active Jumpers"
        ds = dbConn.FillDataSet(sql)
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            tmpJL = New Trident.Objects.Maintenance.JumperLogs.JumperLog(dr)

            message.Body += "Jumper Log # " & tmpJL.LogId & " - Installed: " & tmpJL.InstallDate & vbCrLf

            message.Body += "Mill: " & Trident.Core.Globals.TridentApp.DefaultPlant.Description & vbCrLf
            message.Body += "Facility: " & tmpJL.FacilityObject.Description & vbCrLf
            If Not tmpJL.MachineAreaObject Is Nothing Then
                message.Body += "Area: " & tmpJL.MachineAreaObject.Description & vbCrLf
            End If
            If Not tmpJL.LocationObject Is Nothing Then
                message.Body += "Location: " & tmpJL.LocationObject.Description & vbCrLf
            End If
            If Not tmpJL.EquipmentObject Is Nothing Then
                message.Body += "Equipment: " & tmpJL.EquipmentObject.Description & vbCrLf
            End If

            message.Body += "Installed  By: " & tmpJL.InstalledBy.FullName & vbCrLf
            'message.Body += "Install Date: " & tmpJL.InstallDate & vbCrLf
            message.Body += "Tag: " & tmpJL.Tag & vbCrLf
            message.Body += "Tag Attached To: " & tmpJL.TagAttachedTo & vbCrLf
            message.Body += "Work Order: " & tmpJL.WorkOrder & vbCrLf
            message.Body += vbCrLf
            message.Body += "Reason: " & tmpJL.Reasons.ToUpper & vbCrLf
            message.Body += vbCrLf
            message.Body += "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" & vbCrLf
            message.Body += vbCrLf


        Next

        message.Send()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New PCA.Core.Exceptions.PCAErrorException(ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Now i think that modifying the if statement that initializes the range, might do it?

***Ok a user that is in "JL_001" group recieved a summary email on monday that JL_001 group is label by facilities and this one is called #1paper machine" since. he is only in one group that paper machine group he got one email with only one active jumperlog which happens to be from his facility (#1 paper Machine.) Now this is the issue, there is a group of  users that have all been added to groups "JL_001 to JL_070". since there was only one acitve log entered that previous week on monday they should only get one summary email because they are also in the #1 paper machine facility group(JL_001). they shouldnt receive anything else from any other group because there were no active logs from those groups yet they recieved 70 emails of that same summary pretaining to JL_001. Does this help clear it up?***

Comment: `message.Send()` is only called once, how is any one user receiving multiple messages?

Comment: You are sending emails to many people (via adding their email addresses as recipients of one message); you want some of these people to not get emails under certain conditions; and you are asking whether you should come up with something to affect the aforementioned part (where the emails are being added)?! Yes, you will definitively have to change this part somehow. This was your question, isn't it? Honestly, not sure about the exact relevance of all what you are telling us or of including the whole code (rather than just where the addresses are being added, because the sending part works).

Comment: @David the message has many recipients.

Comment: @varocarbas: Including the same recipients multiple times?  I would think the mail server would be smart enough to correct that.  If not, filtering the recipients to only *distinct* email addresses seems pretty trivial.

Comment: @David Honestly, I am not sure if this issue is automatically corrected or not. But I assumed that this code worked fine (the OP is not complaining about it working fine) without analysing the exact reason (are various emails being sent every time or even the same user might have different addresses or is this function called multiple times?). The whole point of my comment was highlighting that the fact of calling `message.Send()` just once wasn't so relevant here.

Comment: @varocarbas: It might be, if the OP can provide some debugging information.  We can *assume* that the same email addresses exist multiple times in the recipient list, but it's equally possible that this method is itself being invoked multiple times and there is additional logic not demonstrated here.  Either way, the OP really needs to clarify.  We can't debug this for him.

Comment: We definitely don't have enough of the code to see the issue. If there are 70 groups, that means 70 distinct emails which means the message.send() should be either 70 times or in some loop that is called for each group. Look back at the code that calls this routine and see where/how it is supposed to limit the effect of this routine.

Comment: The issue is obviously with `Where r.Id.Contains("JL_")` because that is the same for each loop. Should this be a variable passed to this routine?

Comment: i added something to post to help clear up confusion

Answer (score 0):

You should be building the message body for each recipient, and then send your messages by recipient instead of group. You could do this by following these steps:

1. Create a global list of recipients
2. Get the list of recipients a group
3. Loop through the recipients list. If the recipient already exists, append the additional message body to their record. If not, create a new record in the global list.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 through all groups.
5. Loop through the global list of recipients, and send one message per recipient.